# DAX: FIND or SEARCH part of a string in a column?

Tags: powerbi, dax

I want a custom column to search a part of a text within another column.

For example, I want to find out if `"TRF"` is in column `Descrição do Movimento`

```
Data Mov.   Data Valor  Descrição do Movimento  Valor em EUR
17-02-2017  17-02-2017  CONSTITUICAO 123/004    -2.000
17-02-2017  17-02-2017  TRF 0000082 CUSTOMER A  368
17-02-2017  17-02-2017  TRF 0000082 CUSTOMER B  66
17-02-2017  17-02-2017  TRF 0000082 CUSTOMER C  98
17-02-2017  17-02-2017  TRF 0000082 CUSTOMER D  861
```

This is the code I'm trying to the calculated column:

```
Column = FIND("TRF";'ContaBancoX'[Descrição do Movimento])
```

And also:

```
Column = SEARCH("TRF";'ContaBancoX'[Descrição do Movimento])
```

Both returning the error:

```
The search Text provided to function 'SEARCH' could not be found in the given text.
```

And all the rows return `#ERROR`

How to fix this?
Thanks in advance!

PS: Here's a link for the table:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1vc6c4rV7-NpE1ClbF0dYcWa0PhH4hIMr38QU4EFKuxc/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using:

```
Calculated column = FIND("TRF",[Descrição do Movimento],1,BLANK())
```

It search for `TRF` in the `[Descrição do Movimento]` starting from the first (third argument: 1) character, if is not found returns fourth argument: `BLANK`, otherwise returns the position where the string was found.

Comment: Yes, that works. But, aren't the 3rd and 4th argumens optional?

Comment: @NunoNogueira, I've found that Power BI sometimes requires to specify the "optional" arguments. Particulary faced the same issue using regional settings for Spanish (LA), then changed my settings to English USA and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

I have faced the same issue. Try

```
=IFERROR(FIND("TRF";'ContaBancoX'[Descrição do Movimento]);0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Worked for me in Power BI

```
Column = SEARCH("TRF", YOURTABLE[YOURCOL],1,"-1")
```